# Nodejs output -Domain name not found

Tags: javascript, node.js

Technically this is my first try in nodejs and frankly I am not sure if I am doing it right. I am creating a local server that will stream the output from a distant server. However, when I run my code and I enter a URL in the browser, the program fails with the following message:

```
events.js:45
    throw arguments[1]; // Unhandled 'error' event
                   ^
Error: ENOTFOUND, Domain name not found
at IOWatcher.callback (dns.js:74:15)
```

The URL I used was: 127.0.0.1:9000/http://www.yahoo.fr. And in the browser I had the following message:

**No data received
    Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data.
    Here are some suggestions:
    Reload this web page later.
    Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data.**

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Here is the code:

```
var base, dest, node_client,
count = 0,
url = require('url'),
util = require('util'),
http = require('http'),
http_client = require('http'),
request = require('request'),
events = require('events'),  
httpProxy = require('./lib/node-http-proxy'),

data_emitter = new events.EventEmitter();

httpProxy.createServer(9000, 'localhost').listen(8000);

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    if(!count)
    { 
        base = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
        node_client = http_client.createClient(80, base);
        count++;
    } else {
        dest = req.url.substr(1, req.url.length -1);
    }

    request = node_client.request("GET", dest, {"host": base});
    request.addListener("response", function (response) {
        var body = "";
        response.addListener("data", function (data) {
            body +=data;
        }); 

        response.addListener("end", function () {
            var out = JSON.parse(body);
            if(out.length > 0) {
                data_emitter.emit("out", out);
            }
        });
    });

   // request.close();

    var listener = data_emitter.addListener("data", function(out) {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        res.write(JSON.stringify(out));
        res.close();
    });



}).listen(9000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for any newbie like me in this area, here is how I solved it. It's not clean and can be implemented in better way. Feel free to change, give suggestions.
Code:

```
var url = require('url'),
http = require('http'),
request = require('request'),
httpProxy = require('./lib/node-http-proxy'),
des = '',

util = require('util'),
colors = require('colors'),

is_host = true;

httpProxy.createServer(9000, 'localhost').listen(8000);

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
var pathname = '';

if(is_host) {
    dest = req.url.substr(0, req.url.length -1);
    pathname = dest;
    is_host = false;
} else {
    pathname = req.url.substr(0, req.url.length);
    if(pathname.charAt(0) == "/") {
        console.log('new request');
        console.log(pathname);
        pathname = dest + pathname;
    }
}

console.log(pathname);
request.get({uri: pathname}, function (err, response, html) {
        res.end(html);
});
console.log('fetched from ' + pathname);
});

server.listen(9000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess : your browser automatically requests `127.0.0.1:9000/favicon.ico` and your program then tries to resolve `favicon.ico` which obviously fails and makes your program crash before it can send any data for the *real* request.

Comment: This is why I have 2 variables(base and dest) that store the uri. I'm supposing that the requests are somewhat sequential and that request to www.yahoo.fr will come before /favicon.ico.

Comment: You can always cd into the directory where your code resides and execute the following command:  touch favicon.ico

Answer (score 0):

Why such tangled code?

This is a scenario where it makes sense to avoid nested callbacks, and use named functions. If you refactor the code, then people are more likely to be help you.

Comment: Well, I guess is just because I'm not too familiar with javascript and/or nodejs syntax that I kept it that way.

Comment: @Michael - Fair comment, but not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do `console.log(out)` in your listener callback?  Let us know if Node.js has any response data to return.

Comment: Can you return some static json content instead of the out variable.  See if the response comes back fine to the client...